# Connection lines to have text appear when I hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

Right now when you hold and click on each circle text appear; when you let go of the mouse click, the text goes away. For the lines that connect to each different circles (countries) I'd like them to have text as well that are clickable just like the circles. How can I have text appear on the connection lines when I hover over the line?

Go to the codepen (https://codepen.io/apextrea/pen/JMXmgY) to see more.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var drawOptions = {     
        // dimensions of svg element 
        SVG_WIDTH:        800,
        SVG_HEIGHT:       600,  
        SHRINK_FACTOR: 100,
        BIG_CIRCLE: 200
    };
}
```

Comment: Updated the title. Moved old title into the question body. Reformatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Codepen DEMO](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/NXrRQR)

**Changes in the new code:**

1. You have a dragstart and dragend events bound to the circles. Similarly, now the lines too have these events.

   ```
   d3.selectAll('line.connector').call(d3.drag()
       .on('start', displayConnectorName)
       .on('end', removeName));
   ```

   For displaying the name, I'm using a similar function as you do for the circles but in this case, the position will vary obviously.

   Here's the function:

   function displayConnectorName(d) {
                   var thisLine = d3.select(this);

   ```
               var textX = (+thisLine.attr('x1')+(+thisLine.attr('x2')))/2;
               var textY = (+thisLine.attr('y1')+(+thisLine.attr('y2')))/2;

               //create a text element
               //give it an id so it can be deleted at drag end
               //attributes are based on the line being dragged

               d3.select('svg')
                   .append('text')
                   .attr('id', 'dragName')
                   .attr('x', textX)
                   .attr('y', textY).attr('dx', '-3em')
                   .text(d.source + ' - ' + d.target)
                   .attr('font-size', 20)
       .attr('fill', 'orange');
   ```

   }

   For **removing** this name, the same `removeName` function is used as the `id` attached to the `text` is the same as for circles i.e. `dragName`
2. **Positions** for the texts are around the center of the lines as of now and the texts are

> source-target

But I think, you can take it from here and change them as per the requirements.

3. The circles represent **states** and not countries. :)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks so much shashank, that's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if you face any issues in positioning the names, I'll help with that. If not, please accept the answer so that the issue can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the tool-tip. 
It can be implement by appending `svg:title` element to each circle.
Next browser will show the tooltip and you don't have to worry about hover event.

Follow the below links: They might help you to understand what you need.

https://github.com/caged/d3-tip

http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579